# Is it safe to edit the global PATH environment variable?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, security, environment-variables, path

I just recently found out that I couldn't run mysql without typing out the whole path or being in the correct directory--unless I added the path to the PATH environment variable.

I managed to do so and now I'm able to run mysql upon start-up of my command line. I'm lazy and didn't want to type out the whole path just to run mysql from cmd. Also, I didn't know of any other way to do it. I randomly came across the solution on a forum.

The only thing I'm wondering now is if this is OK/safe to do for all of my programs.

While it isn't practical, it's just a precaution.

I noticed that in some tutorials online, some people had a PATH variable for their user variable while I didn't. I only found the PATH environment variable in the system variables section. Is that a bad thing?

The only account on my PC is the administrator account. At least, that's the only account I use.

Can I get some clarity/input on this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's usually nothing dangerous about adding directories to `PATH`. It could only cause you problems in two ways:

1. While using a command prompt, you might accidentally run a program you didn't intend to. Then again, if you know the programs you put on your `PATH`, nothing malicious will happen.
2. Programs might find DLLs there that usually aren't loaded. The [DLL search order](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx#search_order_for_desktop_applications) specifies that if a requested DLL can't be found in normal locations, it will finally be looked for in the `PATH` places. If, say, a program optionally loaded a module by trying to load a DLL by name and not caring if it fails, someone with control of a `PATH` folder could cause that program to load an arbitrary DLL if one with its name isn't found earlier in the search. Incidentally, that possible security issue is why it's a bad idea to attempt to load DLLs that may or may not be present. Well-written programs won't have this problem.

You could also conceivably [max out the `PATH` variable length](https://superuser.com/q/635082/380318), but that's not really a security issue.

Concerning your not finding the user `PATH` variable: if you create a per-user version of that variable, your effective `PATH` will be the system one automatically combined with your per-user one.

Comment: Thanks. You pretty much covered everything I needed assurance in. Greatly appreciated. I don't normally like granting accepted answers until I've received ample feedback, but your response covered everything and more. Also, I sincerely doubt anyone else would bother to answer my question.